# AngularJs broadcast repeating execution too many times when call a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Angular JS**

```
unified.controller('YourteamController', function uniYourteamController($scope) {    
    $scope.$on('selectchange', function() { 
        alert("Child controller");
    });
});    

unified.controller('testController', function testController($scope) {
    $scope.changeTeam = function(value){
            $scope.$broadcast('selectchange');
    };    
});
```

Here I can call a function from parent controller. But it execute that function 3 times. How can fix this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Have the child controller know when the route changes?

Comment: yes, controller knows

Comment: What router are you using?  ui-router or ngRoute?

Comment: How is $scope.changeTeam() called?

Comment: @Nivin how are you assiging controller `YourteamController` for your template?

Comment: @PankajParkar  unified.directive('uniYourteam', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        replace : true,
        controller : 'uniYourteamController',
        templateUrl : 'app/templates/pages/yourteam.html',
        scope : {
        }
    };
});

Answer (score 0):

There are event-based ways of knowing when a route has changed.  You can hook into any of the events that the ngRouter broadcasts for this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   // Your code
});

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
   // Your code
});

$scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(next, current) { 
   // Your code
});
```